# Count the occurrence of name changing With AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a simple things using `AngularJs` but unable to do so. My requirement - There will be a `TextBox` and user should type in it. Say as the following:

```
<body ng-controller="EmployeeController">
  <div ng-repeat="m in Employees">
    <input type="text" ng-model="m.name" ng-change="m.onCount()">
    <h2>Count the occurrence of name changing {{m.employeeCount}}.</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

The `onCount` function will work when user starts typing and when the word length is equal to one. Now the issue is, using my below code, it counts double:

```
 employee.onCount = function () {
    if (employee.name.length == 1) {
       employee.employeeCount += 1;
    }
 };
```

Double means, suppose, I am typing a `Text` say **John**, it counts 1 and when I erase it, then again, it counts 1. So total becomes 2. It shouldn't count the erased one. I am not able to figure out how can I prevent the counting for the erased one? Here is the below code for creating employee object and it's function using factory:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.factory('employeeService', function () {
        var createDefaultEmployee = function () {
            var employee = {
                name: "",
                employeeCount: 0
            };

            employee.onCount = function () {
                if (employee.name.length == 1) {
                    employee.employeeCount += 1;
                }
            };
            return employee;
        };

        return {
            createEmployee: function (name) {
                var employee = createDefaultEmployee();
                employee.name = name;
                return employee ;
            }
        };
    });

module.controller('EmployeeController', ['$scope', 'employeeService',
     function ($scope, employeeService) {
        $scope.Employees= [employeeService.createEmployee()];
     }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the length of the name is equal zero and subtract one:

```
employee.onCount = function () {
    if(employee.employeeCount > 0 && employee.name.length==0){
       employee.employeeCount--;
    }
    else if (employee.name.length == 1) {
       employee.employeeCount++;
    }
 };
```

Comment: Worked perfectly @Hoyen. Thanks.